# Unable to understand the Express server concept using Node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I was referring to some online tutorials for establishing a Node server using Express 4. I will make my question very simple and easy to understand.

The main app.js file has the following lines (other code lines like middlewares etc. are not show here)

```
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var app = express();

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
```

I have tested the above code. Included the index.js and users.js inside the routes folder. This worked perfect. This means that the http server is already created.

But, my confusion raised, when I say another type of coding done in another site. It has the following lines of code.

```
var express = require('express'),
routes = require('./routes'),
http =require('http’);

var app = express();
```

My first confusion is, why do we need to use the http middleware.

The code further creates a server like this

```
var server = http.createServer(app);
```

Since, I am using the Express framework, why do we need to create the server, this way

Reference can be found here https://github.com/azat-co/practicalnode/blob/master/ch5/blog-express/app.js#L72

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the latter in my code because I need to pass `server` to socketio, not an express app object. Your reference code could have had a need at one point for the http module? Hard to say. I'd love a more thorough answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the developer wanted to create a raw http server for some other specific use later on? Strictly speaking, it is not necessary to do that.

The following is perfectly sufficient to create an http server and begin listening for connections using express:

```
var express = require('express');
app = express();
app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

in express best way is:

```
app = express();
app.listen(3000);
```

in theory this:

```
var server = http.createServer(app);
```

could be used to reuse http server, for example to run sockets.
But app.listen also return http server like http.createServer(app);
We can do:

```
var server = http.createServer(app);   
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

But we also can:

```
var server = app.listen(3033);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

When createServer(app) may be useful? if we want listen to http i https:

```
http.createServer(app).listen(80);
https.createServer(options, app).listen(443);
```